# Using Laravel Blades

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

i have started working in Laravel, and working with .blade.php templates, but am not able to understand the benefit for using blad.php and also while having a master page, why we put our code in some other pages with @sections and @yeild
like

masterpage.blade.php

```
<div>
 @yeild(section)
</div>
```

index.balde.php

```
@section
 Hellow world
@endsection
```

why i need to do it like that? why we can't just put our Text in the same page instead of doing this method, what are the benefits if we code like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lot of benefits in using Blade with Laravel, please read it here 
http://culttt.com/2013/09/02/using-blade-laravel-4/

Answer (score 3):

The short answer for you questions is we do not need Blade engine in any project. However, using it brings many benefits.

### Simplify script file

Like other templating engine, **Blade** engine simplify your PHP scripts by some replacement such as :

- `<?php echo $foo ?>` changed to `{{ $foo }}` (reduce 8 characters)
- `<?php if ($condition): ?>` changed to `@if ($condition)` (reduce 6 characters)
- `<?php echo trans('lang.key') ?>` changed to `@lang('lang.key')` (reduce 11 characters)
- ...

Try to calculate how many character you can save if using **Blade** engine in your script.

Another thing I love in **Blade** engine is that we can create our own custom control structure. If you are tired of typing `$var->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` every time you need to output a `DateTime` object. You can create custom matcher with **Blade**

```
Blade::extend(function($view, $compiler)
{
    $pattern = $compiler->createMatcher('datetime');

    return preg_replace($pattern, '$1<?php echo $2->format('m/d/Y H:i'); ?>', $view);
});
```

Now, all you need to to is replace `$var->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')` by `@datetime($var)`.

### View inheritant

By supporting *section*, *Blade* engine help developer organize their view file in a hierarchical and logical way. Imagine that you have HTML code for some pages of your website: a home page, a category archive page and a single post page. All there page have the same header, footer and sidebar. If we " put our Text in the same page instead of doing this method", the content of there files have a large amount of similarities, which cause any changes in the future very painful.

With **Blade** sections, create a simple *master* layout file like that

```
<html>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            <!-- this is header code -->
        @show
        @section('sidebar')
            <!-- this is sidebar code -->
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>

        @section('footer')
            <!-- this is footer code -->
        @show
    </body>
</html>
```

In the view file for each page, you only need to take care of the main content of the page, instead of other parts.

Comment: I would be curious to know how much overhead this has on the server.  Yes it improves programming speed, but if you want to speed up using php then use built in snippet functions in VSCode or KomodoEdit ... Writing less, will have downside of efficiency when Laravel has to convert that plain text into php scripting